# Button to turn change AllowEdits to true in Access using VB

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying  create a button which changes the value of AllowEdits to False and another for true for a subform. I am using the below code. I get a Runtime error 424  each time I run it.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Toggle_Edit_Click()
    Dim strForm As String

    strFormName = Me.Name
    Call ToggleEdit(Me)
End Sub
```

and

```
Option Compare Database
Public strFormName As String
    Sub ToggleEdit(myForm As Form)
    Call Message
    ctrlControl.AllowEdits = True
End Sub
```

and if you were interested

```
Sub Message()
    MsgBox "Remember not to overwrite incorrect records"
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this code located?  In a form module?  On which line are you getting the error?  For one thing you're passing a form to `ToggleEdit` as a parameter but you're not referring to it within the `ToggleEdit` procedure.  I'm unclear on what you're trying to do `value of AllowEdits to False and another for true`...?

Comment: Fix your code indention! `Sub ToggleEdit(myForm As Form)` is indented below `Public strFormName As String` and looks like it's a part of a block of code. That makes it _very_ hard to read. Also, no need for `Call` that's been deprecated since sometime in the '90s - totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Please add `Option Explicit` at top of your modules!

I think AllowEdits is a `Form` property, not a `Control` property.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ToggleEdit(myForm As Form)
    myForm.AllowEdits = Not myForm.AllowEdits
End Sub
```

If the code is behind the form itself, you can use `Me`.

```
Sub ToggleEdit()   'no parameter
    Me.AllowEdits = Not Me.AllowEdits
End Sub
```

If you want to act at control level, use `Locked` or `Enabled` properties.

Comment: `Me.AllowEdits = Not Me.AllowEdits` Omg, I never thought this use of `Not` in this way. I'm so noob sometimes! Epic one!